# Stack divs vertically with different child alignment

Tags: html, css, flexbox

http://s4.postimg.org/mbrpxn2d9/Untitled.png

Edit: Not a duplicate. The other question doesn't contain information about divs being automatically adjusted to the words on the inside.

I have 4 divs. I have 3 divs inside another div, and I'm trying to float one to the left, one to the center, and one to the right. I'm also trying to make the width and height of the divs on the inside to be automatically adjusted to the width and height of the words on the inside of the divs. I also want the divs on the inside to stack up on top of each other, instead of being on the same line. So far, I got the left div to float to the left, and the right div to float to the right, but I just cannot get the middle div to be centered, nor get it to adjust to the width and height of the word inside of it. Please take a look at my code:

```css
#outer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
#innerLeft {
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
}
#innerMiddle {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: auto;
}
#innerRight {
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id='outer'>
  <div id='innerLeft'>Left</div>
  <div id='innerMiddle'>Middle</div>
  <div id='innerRight'>Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post a picture of the final output that you expect?

Comment: @suslov Not duplicate. Explained above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the output of the image, I think flexbox solution would be a good way to go.

1. Let the container have a flexible layout with column wrapping.
2. Align each item based on position in the container i.e. `flex-start`, `center` and `flex-end`

```css
#outer {
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap; /* Wrap the items column wise */
  justify-content: flex-start; /* Items to start from the top of the container */
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
#innerLeft {
  align-self: flex-start; /* Equivalent to float: left of your code */
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#innerMiddle {
  align-self: center; /* Equivalent to margin: auto */
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#innerRight {
  align-self: flex-end; /* Equivalent to float: right */
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id='outer'>
  <div id='innerLeft'>Left</div>
  <div id='innerMiddle'>Middle</div>
  <div id='innerRight'>Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect! Can you explain parts of the details containing the flex key-word with comments on the side, inside of the code for me please?

Comment: I just added the comments. Let me know if you have any more doubts.

Comment: Why is there both a display: flex, and also a display: -ms-flex?

Comment: I added that for partial support of IE10. This code supports all major browsers and IE11.

Comment: Does flex or ms-flex support all major browsers? I assume it's flex because it's the first one you put, right?

Comment: I see. So basically flex support almost everything, and ms-flex is for support of IE10.

Answer (score 2):

If changing your HTML just a bit is an option, you can add span elements in your divs which will give you want, and it will work in all browsers:

```css
#outer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
#innerLeft {
    text-align:left;
}
#innerMiddle {
    text-align:center;
}
#innerRight {
    text-align:right;
}
div > div > span {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id='outer'>
  <div id='innerLeft'><span>Left</span></div>
  <div id='innerMiddle'><span>Middle</span></div>
  <div id='innerRight'><span>Right</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you mean?? I had Edited

```css
#outer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
#innerLeft {
  border: 1px solid red;
  /* width: 30%; */
  float: left;
}
#innerMiddle {
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
#innerRight {
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id='outer'>
  <div id='innerLeft'>LeftLeftLeftLeft</div> <br>
  <div id='innerMiddle'>MiddleMiddleMiddleMiddle</div> <br>
  <div id='innerRight'>RightRightRightRight</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No. Middle should be below Left. And Right should be Below Middle. Also, none of the divs on the inside should have any width and height. The width and height should be automatically adjusted to the width and height of the words inside of them. I provided a link above of the drawing of what I want it to look like. Please take a look at it.

Comment: Middle's not adjusted to the middle. It's floated to the left.

Comment: But it's really close.

Comment: If you want to adjust to the middle, you should not set 3 div in a parent

Comment: Wrong. It's possible to achieve what I'm trying to achieve. There's an accepted answer above. Check it out and run the code snippet to see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

write your html tags like this hope it help!

```
<div id='outer'>
  <div id='innerRight'>Right</div>
  <div id='innerLeft'>Left</div>
  <div id='innerMiddle'></div>
</div>
```